Fetching image and reading body stream removed the preview from Chrome tab
When fetching an image with the fetch API like so:
fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/A-Cat.jpg")

The Chrome network tab will show a preview of the image:

When fetching an image with the fetch API and reading the body stream:
fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/A-Cat.jpg")
  .then(r => r.blob());

The Chrome network tab will show a broken preview of the image:

I'm assuming this happens because Chrome can't read the body stream again and that makes sense. But is there a way to still show the preview correctly in the Chrome network tab? It's very useful for debugging.

Answering my own question here... (thank you Stackoverflow rubber duck)
Cloning the response fixes this.
fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/A-Cat.jpg")
  .then(r => r.clone().blob());

